# Powershell script to detect when a hot spot is in use and edit the registry

Tags: powershell

We have a situation where a number of Reps use there iPhones as hot spots. Not a problem on it's own. However, to prevent over use of data we would like them to Set the Wifi point as Metered when using the iPhone. Again, sounds simple - right?  Enter Microsoft they have locked down the ability to toggle Metered connections to Admin accounts so a Standard user cannot not. WTF!

Not too much of an issue I can script this - Or so I thought!

What I'm looking to do is detect when an iPhone is in use as a hot spot and change a registry value to make it Metered.

I came up with this:

```
$wlan = Netsh.exe wlan show interfaces
$regpath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost"
$keyname = "WiFi"
$regVal = "2"

if ($wlan_.SSID -like '*iPhone*')
{Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name $keyname -Value $regval 
WRITE-HOST "Set Reg Key Value"
}
else
{Set-ItemProperty -Path $regpath -Name $keyname -Value "1" 
Write-Host "No change Made"
}
```

All look generally OK and to some degree it does work. However, I can't sem to pass the right information for the IF statement

```
$wlan_.SSID -like '*iPhone*'
```

Always ends up as False.

I've Tried SSID, NAME, Profile - all information returned by the Netsh command, but somehow the commands retuen isn't including the information. If you run the Variable you can see the information:

```
$wlan

There is 1 interface on the system: 

Name                   : Wi-Fi
Description            : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
GUID                   : ############################
Physical address       : ################
State                  : connected
SSID                   : User iPhone
BSSID                  : ###########################
Network type           : Infrastructure
Radio type             : 802.11n
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
Connection mode        : Profile
Channel                : 1
Receive rate (Mbps)    : 144.4
Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 144.4
Signal                 : 99% 
Profile                : User iPhone 

Hosted network status  : Not available
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something terribly obvious but I thought would return the information stored in there?

```
$wlan_.xxxxx
```

But it doesn't

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wlan_.SSID -like '*iPnone'
False

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wlan_.name

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wlan_.name -like '*iPnone'
False

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $wlan_.name -like 'Wi-Fi'
False
```

I've tried other bits of information and non returned a true result, even when I know it was true - so I'm assuming it's parsing the information across.

Any Ideas are very much appropriated.

To answer some of the obvious things - all our Users use iPhone's and all are named as "User iPhone" It's not intended as a catch all, but a catch most.

Comment: `$wlan` doesn't contain an object, but an array of strings from netsh screen output.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, it never occurred to me it's string I can just Wild card search the whole string and get what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert netsh string output I suggest to use the cmdlet `ConvertFrom-StringData`. It expects an equal sign delimiting property from value so you'll need a RegEx to replace:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\08\03\sf_924794.ps1
$netSh = (Netsh.exe wlan show interfaces | Where-Object {$_ -like '* : *'}) -join "`r`n"
$Wlan = $netsh.Trim() -split '(?m)(?=^Name\b)' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] ($_ -replace '(?m)^(.+?) +: (.+?)$','$1=$2' | ConvertFrom-StringData)
}
$Wlan | Format-Table -AutoSize
$Wlan
```

Sample output:

```
> $Wlan | Format-Table -AutoSize

Transmit rate (Mbps) Hosted network status Network type   BSSID                       Physical address Name  Description
-------------------- --------------------- ------------   -----                       ---------------- ----  -----------
144.4                Not available         Infrastructure ########################### ################ Wi-Fi Intel(R) Dual Band ...

> $Wlan

Transmit rate (Mbps)  : 144.4
Hosted network status : Not available
Network type          : Infrastructure
BSSID                 : ###########################
Physical address      : ################
Name                  : Wi-Fi
Description           : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
Authentication        : WPA2-Personal
Receive rate (Mbps)   : 144.4
Channel               : 1
Cipher                : CCMP
Radio type            : 802.11n
Profile               : User iPhone
Signal                : 99%
Connection mode       : Profile
State                 : connected
SSID                  : User iPhone
GUID                  : ############################
```

That looks quite similar, but from different ordering (due to hashtable) you see that now it's an object with properties you can access as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The fact it returns the whole Output as a String makes this job 100 times easier as I can just search the string for the text I need, rather than have to limit it to an object!

end result is:

```
$wlan = Netsh.exe wlan show interfaces
```

and then
    if ($wlan -like '*iPhone*')

This works for me, in my example.

Thank you very much for your help, I feel like an idiot that I didn't clock it was string!